# is it possible to create a ggMarginal plot without desaggredating the data?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data frame with some points and their frequency of occurrence and I want to plot points (balls) using their frequency to represent their size. But I also want to use *ggMarginal* to create the marginal plots. The code bellow creates the marginal without taking in account their frequencies.

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame("x" = 1:5, "y" = c(5,8,8,12,10), "f" = c(4,5,8,8,5))
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y, size=f)) + geom_point() + theme_bw()
ggExtra::ggMarginal(p, data=df, type = "histogram")
```

[image]

I don't want to create another data frame with disaggregated data. But it would lead to the right marginals. As presented bellow:

```
# disaggregated data
df2 <- df[ rep(1:nrow(df), df$f), c("x", "y") ]
p <- ggplot(df2, aes(x=x, y=y)) + geom_point() + theme_bw()
ggExtra::ggMarginal(p, data=df2, type = "histogram")
```

[image]

But even if I try to use both data frames, the resulting marginals still go wrong.

```
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y, size=f)) + geom_point() + theme_bw()
ggExtra::ggMarginal(p, data=df2, type = "histogram")
```

[image]

1. Is it possible to create the marginals with disaggregating the data? How?
2. If 1. is not possible, how to do it anyway, since none of the examples above provided the desired plot?

Comment: this is the last code... still wrong.

Comment: the marginals in the second plot are right, the others are wrong

Comment: `p <- ggplot(df2, aes(x=x, y=y)) + geom_point() + geom_count() + theme_bw(); ggExtra::ggMarginal(p, data = df2, type = "histogram")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done with `cowplot` package.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(cowplot)

df <- data.frame("x" = 1:5, 
                 "y" = c(5,8,8,12,10), 
                 "f" = c(4,5,8,8,5))
df2 <- df[rep(1:nrow(df), df$f), c("x", "y") ]

p <- 
  ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y, size=f)) + 
  geom_count() + 
  theme_bw()
xhist <- 
  axis_canvas(p, axis = "x") + 
  geom_histogram(data = df2, aes(x = x), color = 'lightgray')
yhist <-
  axis_canvas(p, axis = "y", coord_flip = TRUE) + 
  geom_histogram(data = df2, aes(x = y), color = 'lightgray') +
  coord_flip()
p %>%
  insert_xaxis_grob(xhist, grid::unit(1, "in"), position = "top") %>%
  insert_yaxis_grob(yhist, grid::unit(1, "in"), position = "right") %>%
  ggdraw()
```

[image]